# res.set() header token lost after res.redirect()

Tags: ajax, node.js, authentication, express

After a successful login I create a json session token and add it as a header to the res object. After I redirect the user, the header parameters have been lost. I am not using any authentication middleware.

My ajax call:

```
$('.form-signin').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var json = {
          "email": $('#email').val(),
          "password": $('#password').val(),
        };
        $.ajax({
          url: '/api/login',
          data: json,
          type: "POST"
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR) {
          console.log(jqXHR);
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          console.log('Back to basic');
        });
      });
```

My server side login route handler:

```
app.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
    pg.select().table('admins').where({ email: req.body.email })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.redirect('/');
    })
    .then(function(user) {
        if(user) {
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, function(err, valid) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
                if(!valid) {
                    console.log('Password not valid');
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
                var token = jwt.sign({ email: user[0].email }, app.get('secret'), { expiresInMinutes: 60 });
                res.set('x-auth', token);
                res.redirect('/admin');
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Username not found');
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    })
});
```

Authentication function:

```
var auth = function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-auth'];
    console.log(req.headers);

    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('secret'), function(err, auth) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Token verification failure');
                res.redirect('/');
            }
            pg.select('email').from('admins').where({ email: auth.email })
            .then(function(result) {
                if(result.length) {
                    console.log('Redirected to admin');
                    next();
                } else {
                    console.log('User is not logged in');
                    res.redirect('/');
                }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Database error');
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No token');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};
```

I have added the necessary headers for reading my token as well:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-auth');
    next();
});
```

My auth function always logs "No token" and the req.headers parameter is always (the access-control-allow headers are gone as well):

```
{ host: 'localhost:8080',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  accept: '*/*',
  'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
  'accept-language': 'et' }
```

Now I know that I could respond with the token and send it as data with a second ajax call, but I want to handle the redirect on the server side. Anybody has an idea, what might go wrong here?

Comment: May not be what your looking for but since your using ajax for posting credentials, could you not respond with `res.json({'token': token})` and handle the redirect from the client side success handler (after processing received token)?